# Home Networking: How to set up a network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

## House

- **Upstairs**

  - Room 1

    - RJ11 for VDSL from ISP ends here
    - VDSL modem Comtrend VR-3031eu from ISP

      - 300Mbps Wifi, 100Mbit LAN, 50Mbit VDSL WAN
  - Room 2
  - usually only notebooks are used here on wifi, although there should be at least 1 LAN cable available in each room for intensive workloads from time to time.
- **Downstairs**

  - Room 3

    - Desktop
    - hole drilled through ceiling to Room 1 with LAN cable
  - Room 4

    - Desktop
    - IP TV
    - Notebook
- **Garden**

  - ~ 50m to one side from the router - there are massive stone walls on the ground floor in the line of sight from the modem
  - ideally should have Wifi available

## My plan

- **Keep the 100Mbit Comtrend VR-3031eu modem**
- **Buy Netgear GS108GE switch** (SWITCH1) and connect it to one of the LAN ports on modem
- Connect LAN to SWITCH1 (5+1 ports full)

  - 1xRoom 2
  - 1xRoom 3
  - 3xRoom 4
- **Buy Ubiquiti UniFi UAP-AC-LR** and connect it to switch and position it so that it covers the Rooms, but also has reasonably good coverage of the garden

## Questions

1. Would it be possible (instead of drilling multiple holes through floor in Room 1) to just **use the existing LAN cable from Room 1 to Room 3 and connect another switch (SWITCH2) on the ground floor** and from there connect Room 3 and 4 - SWITCH1 <-through floor-> SWITCH2 <-> 1xRoom3, 3xRoom4? And will it negatively affect performance of IPTV and PCs in Room4 going through 2 switches?
2. Would **all the computers have Gbit to each other**, even though SWITCH1 is connected to router that only has 100Mbit?
3. Will the **100Mbit connection between SWITCH1 and MODEM handle multiple clients well** if the WAN is limited to 50Mbit anyway?
4. If I use the 2 SWITCH scenario, would it be OK to use something cheaper like D-Link DGS-105/E?

Comment: Are you sure it's ADSL? That 50Mbps data rate sounds more like VDSL to me. What is the exact make and model of your DSL modem?

Answer (score 1):

1. There should be no noticeable performance impact by daisy chaining switches.
2. Provided all computers are connected to gigabit switch(es) and the gigabit switches connect to each other (rather than through the router) you can get gigabit speeds. Note that if connecting two gigabit switches together, the link between them limits the speed, so you won't be able to have four computers with two on one switch pulling data from the second faster than 1 gigabit combined (unless you use multiple uplinks and expensive switches).
3. On paper yes. In practice maybe - it depends on the quality of the firmware, software and processor.
4. Yes. Any unmanaged gigabit switch should be fine.